# document.createElement дублируется бесконечно, сам по себе

Tags: javascript

Почему код добавляет в head скрипт бесконечное число раз , пока не остановить выполнение страницы? Мне один раз надо

============спустя 1 час====================
почему то когда слеш поставил перед js то все заработало `loadScript('/js/script.js');` Но всё равно почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл js/sript.js

```
function loadScript(src){
    let script =document.createElement('script');
    script.src=src;
    document.head.append(script);

}
loadScript('js/script.js');
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Git test</title>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
    <p>Second message</p>
    
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Скажите, а зачем вам функция ```loadScript('js/script.js');``` ? Вы ведь руками добавили тег в html, а потом создаёте тоже самое функцией.

Comment: @Макс к учу эту тему https://learn.javascript.ru/callbacks, точнее промисы, но перед этим вникаю в коллбэки. Тут самый первый пример как раз этот код

Comment: В сниппете не воспроизводится ошибка.

Comment: @Grundy , там в консоли надо посмотреть браузера, было бы классно если бы Вы у себя проверили на компьютере. Вы та знаете всё

Comment: А какое содержание файла `js/script.js`???

Comment: @Grundy да никакое, учу просто эту тему https://learn.javascript.ru/callbacks там первый пример он как раз, это надо чтобы promise понять

Comment: @РусланКамов, никакое не может быть. Скорее всего, метод `loadScript` находится в загружаемом файле, поэтому он и выполняется при загрузке каждый раз и начинает загружать еще раз. Приведи конкретное содержание всех файлов js, html которые у тебя есть.

Comment: @Grundy ну я же в снипеты скопировал всё.

Comment: В сниппете проблема не воспроизводится, это раз. В сниппете нет содержимого файла `js/script.js`, то есть неизвестно что именно ты загружаешь и выполняешь. Не указано где именно расположена и когда вызывается функция `loadScript`. Из-за этого можно только гадать, что пошло не так.

Comment: @Grundy смотри, файл script.js, я в нем прописываю функцию которая создает элемент script, добавляет в него аттрибут src( с входящим аргументом функции) и жду чтобы в шапку просто добавил мне этот тег с нужными мне аттрибутами. Но по факту получается что я вызываю два раза скрипт с которого программирую? Но все равно почему так много раз дублируется?

Comment: Вместо сниппета, который не демонстрирует ошибку, которую ты получаешь, добавь конкретное содержимое твоего html и всех твоих файлов js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что функция `loadScript` и ее вызов находятся в загружаемом файле.

Из-за этого, при загрузке файла функция выполняется и начинает опять загружать файл, в котором функция для загрузки файла и так безконечно.

Для решения достаточно вынести вызов метод `loadScript` из загружаемого файла.

файл js/sript.js

```
console.log('script loaded');
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Git test</title>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
    <p>Second message</p>
    
    <script>
        function loadScript(src){
            let script =document.createElement('script');
            script.src=src;
            document.head.append(script);
        }
        loadScript('js/script.js');
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть файл, в котором вы создаёте и подключаете **этот же файл**, из-за этого действие попадает в рекурсию.
А когда вы добавляете к подключаемому файлу путь со слешем вначале, то этот файл не загружается (404) и рекурсии нет.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: спасибо огромное, жаль 2 ответа лучшими нельзя признать